# Why does glGenFramebuffers not work with OpenGL 3.2?

Tags: c++, opengl

When I run my program with OpenGL 3.1 it works fine but when I use OpenGL 3.2, `glGenFramebuffers` gives a segfault. I tried using `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` and this allows the program to run without giving an error but the screen is completely black. I should also mention I'm using the CG Toolkit version 3.1. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, glGenX functions should not be able to crash - all they do is give you a free handle you can use afterwards.

Thus, this sounds like a problem with GLEW. Have you stepped into it to see that you're not calling a null pointer function?